# Subdomain routing in ASP.NET Core 3.0 RazorPages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.0 with razor pages, and I want to route `sub1.test.local` to `Pages/Sub1` and `sub2.test.local` to `Pages/Sub2`. I tried create custom page convention, but this is completely different from MVC routes, so I'm asking here.

Answer (score 2):

Michael Graf has post about this.

You first need to create custom Router by overriding MvcRouteHandler, then you need to use this Router class inside your Mvc Routes configuration.

```
public class AreaRouter : MvcRouteHandler, IRouter
{
    public new async Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
    {
        string url = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["HOST"];

        string firstDomain = url.Split('.')[0];
        string subDomain = char.ToUpper(firstDomain[0]) + firstDomain.Substring(1);

        string area = subDomain;

        context.RouteData.Values.Add("area", subDomain);

        await base.RouteAsync(context);
    }
}
```

In Startup config,

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.DefaultHandler = new AreaRouter();
            routes.MapRoute(name: "areaRoute",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
        });
    }
```

Comment: razor pages also use app.UseMvc so the configuration must be similar.

Comment: It is [available](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/321327f84b2b22dcff2e9beb06a9a64236c5cced/src/Mvc/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Routing/MvcRouteHandler.cs) you may also consider to override RouteHandler class. But I didn't tried it

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu, thanks for your answer. In my project I'm developing a multi-tenant website, I need to reject unrecognized tenants, so that the page returns an error if the tenant isn't found in the database, is `MvcRouteHandler` good for that too?

Comment: MvcRouteHandler in .NET 5: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Mvc/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Routing/MvcRouteHandler.cs